# Datatable in PrimeFaces does not show the SortBy arrows

Tags: sorting, primefaces, datatable

I had already made ​​several pages of my PrimeFaces project that showed a DataTable with SortBy function and worked perfectly, but now, i notice, i don't know why, in all my project, DataTables does not appear Sort function. Not even see the arrows in the headers, and you can not click on the headers .... is as if I had accidentally disabled in some way, the possibility that they may have the function Sort.
I tried to make a new project and if it works Sort perfectly, so it must be due to something I've added it in the last source code modifications, but I have no idea what can be.

Can anyone help? Any idea what may be the reason why in the datatables not display the Sort function?

Comment: Please post your code. How else are we supposed to help you?

Comment: The problem is I don't know where the problem can be. I am working for days without look any datatable, and i don't know in that moment, in the last days, I made the problem reason. There are a lot of code lines for public all here... I was thinking that anyone, as expert, could have an idea the what can cause this problem...

Comment: Not even an expert can help you without looking at your code. The people on here are experts, not psychics. Personally, I can only give you general debugging practices: if you have it working in one place (e.g, if you have your old code, or some other code) and not another (your main application), try slowly changing the working code to look more and more like your non-working code until something breaks. Once it breaks you know your problem.

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't mean to sound rude (sorry if I do); I'm just trying to be direct. :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but what you say is just what I pretended to avoid ... because it takes a lot of time. I still think someone may have had this problem and can give me any clue what could be the problem.
If I find the cause of the problem I'll post. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't think so but it could even be a bug, you should at least state what version of primefaces you are using.